SQL: query to select all records from join table with specific WHERE condition
I have join table (from relation OneToMany-ManyToOne):



warehouse_group_id
warehouse_id




1
1


2
1


4
1


4
2


5
1


5
2



I want to receive only these records  which contain some specific warehouse_id. Eg for warehouse_id = 2 I want to receive the last 4 records because warehouse_group_id with id 4 contains records where there is 2 in column warehouse_id. The same case for warehouse_group_id with id 5
What query should I prepare?

This seems like a basic select warehouse_group_id from your_table where warehouse_id = 2, if not , please add further explanation

SELECT warehouse_group_id FROM my_table WHERE warehouse_id = :warehousId?

Please clarify your expected output

No, warehouse_group_id can have many different warehouse_id

I clarified my expected output

A [mcve] is expected to include both sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt, and add a tag for the dbms used.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

You can use next solution:
select distinct wh.*
from w 
join w as wh on w.warehouse_group_id = wh.warehouse_group_id
where w.warehouse_id = 2;

Result as expected return 4 rows:



warehouse_group_id
warehouse_id




4
1


4
2


5
2


5
1



Test on online fiddle

You can create a view with below syntax:
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name1
Inner join table_name2

Once view is created now you can use it like a table:
select * from view_name where warehouse_id = 2


I use Spring Boot, repository with JPA and I don't want to use views

Can you please share what query is currently used?

i don't have any query yet, I want to receive all warehouse_group_id that contain warehouse_id = 2. In this example we see that there are two warehouse_group_id that have warehouse_id = 2

So if you want warehouse_group_id that has warehouse_id= 2 then it is just a simple statement SELECT warehouse_group_id FROM my_table WHERE warehouse_id = :warehousId If this is not the case from what I understand then please clarify it properly.

OK, I edited my post a little bit. I want to receive thhe whole record with all columns. So in my example I want to receive the last 4 records

FROM your_table
WHERE warehouse_group_id IN (
    SELECT warehouse_group_id
    FROM your_table
    WHERE warehouse_id = 2
);```
I got the requirement so why don't you try like this.
